# Comparing two list using linq

Tags: linq, list

[image]

I have two list as shown in the picture. what i want output is need to remove the state from the list 2 which is not present in the list 1, like shown below. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Whert fancy drawings but StackOverflow is not intended for "write me code doing this and that".

Comment: @Konrad Kokosa: Sorry for that, im the beginner at linq..so im not getting any idea. thatsy seeking for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typical inner join, hence you can use LINQ `Join` method:

```
var list3 = list2.Join(list1, x => x.State, y => y.State, (x, y) => x)
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Intersect method

```
var list1 = new [] {1,2,4};
var list2 = new [] {1,2,3};
list1.Intersect(list2);
```

This will give the result 1,2

Or, if you are using a class you created you will need to create a comparer to tell the intersect method what is equal to what.

```
        var productList1 = new List<Product>();
        productList1.Add(new Product { Code = 1, Name = "Pears" });
        productList1.Add(new Product { Code = 2, Name = "Rasbries" });
        productList1.Add(new Product { Code = 3, Name = "Apple" });

        var productList2 = new List<Product>();
        productList2.Add(new Product { Code = 1, Name = "Pears" });
        productList2.Add(new Product { Code = 2, Name = "Rassbeyreys" });
        productList2.Add(new Product { Code = 4, Name = "Avocado" });

        var result = productList1.Intersect(productList2, new ProductComparer());


public class ProductComparer : IEqualityComparer<Product>
{
    public bool Equals(Product x, Product y)
    {
        return x.Code == y.Code;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Product obj)
    {
        return obj.Code;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you think this is the answer please select it :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i=0;i<list2.Count;i++)
{
    if(!list1.Select(p=>p.State).Contains(list2[i].State))
    {
        list2.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

or:

```
var improve_list2 = (from c in list2
                     where list1.Select(p=>p.State).Contains(c.State)
                     select c).ToArray();
```